# Min 3 elements in foreach Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection where can be maximum 3 elements. Can be 1 element, can be 2 elements. If I have only 1 element, or 2 elements in collection I need check it and add html.

My code:

```
@foreach($collections->take(3)->get() as $collection)
    {{ $collection->name }}
    @if($collections->count() == 1)
       <div>empty</div>
    @endif
    @if($collections->count() == 2)
       <div>empty</div>
       <div>empty</div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I need get this result:

```
Collection name
empty
empty
```

Or If I have 2 elements in collection, I need get result:

```
Collection name
Collection name
empty
```

If I have 3 elements in collections I need get:

```
Collection name
Collection name
Collection name
```

How I can make it?

Comment: What is your current output? `@elseif` feels like a good idea.  Shouldn't the condition block be outside of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why your current code wouldn't work, but you can have a go at the following approach.

Loop through the collection limited by 3 as you were, then afterwards, run a `for` loop - if the `$collections->count()` is 2, then `3-2 = 1`, so you get 1 iteration of the for-loop. If the count is 3 or higher, the condition of the `for` loop is never true, and it doesn't print anything.

```
@foreach($collections->take(3)->get() as $collection)
    {{ $collection->name }}
@endforeach

@for ($i = 0; $i < 3 - $collections->count(); i++) 
     <div>empty</div>
@endfor
```